# Fogbugz API :: Searching on a custom field

Tags: fogbugz, fogbugz-api

My version of Fogbugz is v8 and I'm trying to use the API to refine results by a custom field that i've created, so far i've got the following:

```
/api.asp?token=[token]&cmd=search&q=project:"=116"+plugin_customfields_at_fogcreek_com_environmentf52:LAMP&cols=sTitle,sPersonAssignedTo,ixBug,environment,product
```

But the API keeps giving me an error saying

```
The requested search axis 'plugin_customfields_at_fogcreek_com_environmentf52' is not recognized.
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer for you, but you may have better luck asking this question at http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @paulStock Hi I've posted there aswell hoping that someone will know..

Comment: OK, hopefully between the 2 locations someone will know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
/api.asp?token=[token]&cmd=search&q=project:"=116"&plugin_customfields_at_fogcreek_com_environmentf52:LAMP&cols=sTitle,sPersonAssignedTo,ixBug,environment,product
```

You use `&` instead of `+` to indicate different search criteria.